# java Object inside a try {}

Tags: java

Hy ... I have the following code :

```
    try { Nrtrde record = new Nrtrde(); }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" ERROR\n");
        e.printStackTrace(); }
    finally { Nrtrde record = new Nrtrde(); System.out.println(" OK\n"); }

record.setSpecificationVersionNumber(specificationVersionNo);
```

and when compiling i get the following error :

```
NRTRDE\ENCODER.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        record.setSpecificationVersionNumber(specificationVersionNo);
        ^
  symbol:   variable record
  location: class ENCODER
1 error
```

It seems I cannot create an object insinde a `try {}` and use it outside `try {}` ..

Why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare it outside the block, but you can initialize it inside the block:

```
Nrtrde record = null;
try { 
    record = new Nrtrde();
} catch (SomeException e) {
    // handle exception here
}
if(record!=null){
    // do something with it
}
```

In Java, `{}` are block delimiters. Nothing is visible outside the block it is defined in. (Class members are an exception to this rule if the visibility allows it).

Answer (score 3):

Because its scope is limited to {}. It wont be recognized outside. Thats why you are getting this error

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that case your object will exist until you program will exit the try block. That is because it is scoped by the {}

To make it visible both in the try and finally/catch do something like:

```
Nrtrde record;
 try { record = new Nrtrde(); }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" ERROR\n");
        e.printStackTrace(); }
    finally { record = new Nrtrde(); System.out.println(" OK\n"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your record variable is visible only within the try and finally block, you have to declare your Nrtrde before the try-catch-finally block.

Answer (score 0):

A variable can be acccessed only between a pair of curly braces `{ }`.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm